If you're a native speaker of Spanish does this sentence make sense to you?
I found the following sentence on Wikipedia:

Una cuenca hidrográfica es un territorio continental drenado por un único sistema de drenaje natural, es decir, que sus aguas dan al mar a través de un río que vierte sus aguas a un único lago endorreico.

Wikipedia
And I find it to be confusing. Here's my best attempt at translating it:

A drainage basin is a continental territory drained by a single system of natural drainage, in other words, that its waters flow into the sea by means of a river that pours its waters into a single endorheic lake.

I feel like I'm not translating it right because the English version doesn't really make sense. Is this sentence trying to say that the river sends all its water into a lake or into the sea? Seems incoherent to me. What am I missing?
Help appreciated.

I think that probably it's a poor translation of the English version as pointed by "Me Gusta la fruta" below.

no "that" [...] its waters flow into the sea via a river that empties into a single endorheic lake. However, the content is mistaken as those lakes have no outlet to the sea.

The Wikipedia definition was wrong. It's changed now indicating that water flows either to the sea or to a lake.

I looked up "cuenca endorreica" in the Spanish version of Wikipedia, and got a definition that does make sense.
https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuenca_endorreica
Notice that this definition would not apply to "la cuenca del Amazonas", because the Amazon river drains into the ocean.
The definition you offered is confused with regard to whether or not the water ends up in the ocean.  Probably a mistake in Wikipedia.
